# Webpack correctly does not include dead code, but bundles a dependency of the dead code

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have problems with bundling my isomorphic/universal application. For some reason, both treeshaking and uglify completely ignore the fact that MongoDB is not used in any code path and include it into my browser bundle, which makes it really big (1.3 MB) and unusable (because of native Node modules). It should omit all MongoDB related code because it's unused. It even correctly deletes the dead code branch from the bundle, yet the MongoDB dependency is still there, unused.

My entrypoint (index.js):

```
import { TestService } from "../../services/TestService";
import { container, services } from "../../ioc";

const test = container.get("test");
test.retrieveTestMessage.then((result) => console.log(result));
```

ioc.js:

```
// omitted Inversify setup
import { TestService } from "./services/TestService";

if (DEPLOYMENT_NODE == true) // DefinePlugin sets this to false; only the 'else' branch is correctly included in the bundle
{
    container.bind("test").to(TestService);
}
else
{
    container.bind("test").toConstantValue(createClient(API_URL, "test"));
}
```

TestService.js:

```
import { injectable } from "inversify";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

@injectable()
export class TestService
{
    public async retrieveTestMessage()
    {
        if (DEPLOYMENT_NODE == true)
        {
            // omitted MongoClient usage
        }
    }
}
```

createClient function:

```
export function createClient(url, service)
{
    const client = new Proxy(
        {},
        {
            get: (target, property, receiver) => async (...params) => fetch(url, { headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }), method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({ id: 0, service: service, method: property, parameters: params }) }) 
        }
    );

    return client;
}
```

I tried to use `webpack.IgnorePlugin(/mongodb/)` in my Webpack config, and it really does not include MongoDB, but the bundle then fails with "MongoDB module not found" error, even though it's not used at all.

If anybody has any other suggestions, it's highly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm using latest Webpack 2 beta and am preserving ES6 modules in my babel config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit requiring under the `if` condition should work

```
import { injectable } from "inversify";

@injectable()
export class TestService
{
    public async retrieveTestMessage()
    {
        if (DEPLOYMENT_NODE == true)
        {
            const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
            // omitted MongoClient usage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keeping it in the dead zone is the best approach (y)! You can configure an empty module loader, add a custom context resolver,   or use some other Webpack trick to make it work, but that's really going to raise the WTF rate for others.

Comment: I tried to do the explicit require in the "ioc.js" file and it works, I even could delete these if statements from my services; so this is not exactly the answer (but it works correctly), but pushed me in the right direction. Thank you!